# TinkerGraph getLabels() and getTraversals() are making tests to be slow

Tags: gremlin, visualvm, execution-time

I have some integration tests using TinkerGraph (in memory) which take 10-15 seconds each to finish. From monitoring, using VisualVM, I have figured out that the main cause of delay is due to  `TraversalHelper.getLabels()` and `TraversalHelper.getTraversals()` methods.

I was expecting TinkerGraph as it is an in-memory to be blazing fast but it could be that I am doing something wrong or there is indeed some performance issue. My other tests are less than 200ms.. Any help is appreciated!

[image: VisualVM Profiler]

Here is a query that takes 5+ seconds to create 51 vertices with about 4-5 properties each interconnected through 89 edges:

[PasteBin Example](http://pastebin.com/W5mdS4r6)

**UPDATE:** Performance in my tests was improved from ~40s to ~6s  for in-memory tests and from 2mins to under 1min using DSE after using the newly deployed 3.2.5-SNAPSHOT and 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT (from http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/). For more details you can have a look here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1642. I would like to say a big Thanks to stephen mallette for his quick and precise action that yielded great performance improvement not only for the in-memory gremlin traversals but also all the other disk-based graph technologies that use gremlin on top of them.

Comment: What is the nature of your tests? How big is your test graph (i.e. number of edges)?

Comment: less than 20 vertices and edges. The test is just creating a subgraph and inserting it in a single traversal..Each vertex has a label with as() I will send the queries in a bit. thanks :)

Comment: That seems strange. A traversal over 20 vertices/edges shouldn't take 10+ seconds on TinkerGraph. If i were you I would open a Gremlin Console, create my 20 vertex/edge graph in TinkerGraph and then run the traversals you are testing to see if you get the same slow speed. If you do, then edit your question to include the Gremlin code to create the graph and the traversal causing the trouble. If you do not get the same slow speed, then you must have something strange going on in your test environment and you would need to isolate that further.

Comment: will do that and I will come back if I have any strange results! Thanks :)

Comment: @stephenmallette I didn't have time to look into that in depth I am curious if it is slow because I am doing this all over my code: ```if (traversal == null) {
           return graph.inject("1");
        }
        else {
            return traversal;
        }``` so I can continue my traversals no matter what

Comment: i don't think an if statement with the potential for creation of a new `Traversal` instances should be expensive.

Comment: Hi @stephenmallette I was able to add some monitoring specifically on the queries that take time.. I have isolated a single query in a pastebin. I would appreciate if you could have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty massive piece of Gremlin. I'm honestly not sure what to expect in terms of performance on a hunk of Gremlin with 350+ chained statements.

I would offer a few bits of advice. Trying to do all that work in one single line of Gremlin creates code that is hard to read and difficult to maintain. You likely wouldn't try to write your non-Gremlin code that way (no matter what language you are working in), so it's probably good to consider your standard programming techniques when writing Gremlin.

While I'm not sure what the performance should be on this large a hunk of Gremlin, I do know that if you split that statement down into smaller more manageable bits, creating 51 vertices and 89 edges should not take 5+ seconds to run. I don't know what to attribute that difference to offhand, but you are creating a fair amount of overhead for yourself in the traversal with all those step labels, which perhaps explains the endless calls to `getLabels()` that you mentioned in your question.

**Update:** See discussion below

Comment: Thank you! Although I didn't write that myself.. this is a test so it is generating things on the fly based on custom Object mappers that can handle complexity with ease.. the problem is that in production (with DSE Graph) in order for this to be in a single transaction I need to do it in a single query.. that's why I had to take that route.. unfortunately there is no way to do batch update through the fluent api in a single transaction.. The labels I am creating are less than 100 so I am curious if there is proper caching behind the scenes..I will investigate it further but this is in memory!

Comment: Could you please explain if this: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/f5558cd02904c748de3b3cbd403b4858218d5ec1/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/util/TraversalHelper.java#L556 is called on every step and if it is doing that for the whole traversal so far? or when it is actually called? It seems expensive! Thanks :)

Comment: we did look into that, and it looks like it is only called once when traversal requirements are retrieved. in your case, you don't have any recursion either as you don't have a nested traversal. so it's an iteration of 350+ steps only looking for labels. still looking into the problem.

Comment: Note that I created - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1642 - we'll see what can be done to make improvements here on the TinkerPop side of things.

Comment: Thank you @stephenmallette! I will stay tuned for the updates!

Comment: An improvement has been merged in the TinkerPop repo - when tested with TinkerGraph the speed improvement was quite noticeable. I'm not sure when that change will get to DSE Graph and by how much an improvement this change will translate to once it's there, but there definitely was a problem there. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will report hopefully improved results once I have them! Will those changes be reflected to apache maven snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/) e.g 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT or not yet? Thanks :)

Comment: I just deployed 3.2.5-SNAPSHOT and 3.3.0-SNAPSHOT in case you want to try to use them in some way.

Comment: man you are awesome! I just added 3.2.5-SNAPSHOT and my tests that were taking about 40s total now take about 6-7s :D! Can't be happier :)

Comment: same tests with DSE Graph were taking about 2mins and now are under 1min

Comment: thanks for reporting back on that - i'm glad to hear it helped. i don't feel like i'm done making progress there yet, but that was a pretty large body of performance enhancements and it was time we put a stake in the ground and moved the changes to the release branches.

Comment: btw I had a small issue with the somewhat changed api. if possible please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213617/after-gremlin-3-2-5-snapshot-i-cant-pass-an-array-of-vertex-labels-in-function Thanks!