# After Gremlin 3.2.5-SNAPSHOT I can't pass an array of vertex labels in function hasLabel()

Tags: java, gremlin

It used to be that both those statements would work in Java:

```
GraphTraversalSource g =...;
String[] labels = new String[]{"label1","label2","label3"};

g.V().hasLabel(labels);
g.V().hasLabel("label1", "label2", "label3");
```

After upgrading to 3.2.5-SNAPSHOT only the later one is supported and I am getting `"Cannot resolve method hasLabel(java.lang.String[])"`.
Apparently `hasLabel(String label, String... otherLabels)`  collides with `hasLabel(P<String> predicate)`. Is there a work around for that so I can still build a list of labels incrementally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force it to use [`hasLabel(String label, String... otherLabels)`](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.2.4/gremlin-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.java#L974)

```
g.V().hasLabel(labels[0], labels);
```

Comment: Thanks! this is weird though I think both needs to be supported implicitely.. isn't it true?

Comment: Looks like the behavior was changed in [TinkerPop 3.2.2](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/commit/a522bd52c5c1637d9b907ac99b7fac4c019f5527) to enforce that at least 1 argument was passed to the method. If the varargs is first, you could call on the method with no arguments. If you want to discuss further, I'd suggest continuing on the TinkerPop [dev mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@tinkerpop.apache.org).

Comment: The validation we added was nice but it came at the cost of passing in the array of labels. We may or may not have realized this was a breaking change in this respect. At the time, I think I only thought of `g.V().hasLabel("x","y","z")` and figured that the API change was sound.

Comment: Related JIRA issue [TINKERPOP-1443](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1443)